# Delete rows using a GUID key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a performance issue with deleting about 1,000,000 rows from a table using this query:

```
DELETE cr from CrawlRow cr
INNER JOIN Crawl c ON cr.Crawl_Id = c.Id
WHERE c.CrawlRound_Id = 'BE821DFF-3F2F-4850-80A8-10D4EF0275F5'
```

Type of `Crawl.CrawlRound_Id` is `uniqueidentifier` and I have an index defined on it.

**Question 1:** Is converting `'BE821DFF-3F2F-4850-80A8-10D4EF0275F5'` to `Guid` the source of the problem?

**Question 2:** How can I put a `Guid` literal instead of the string literal to avoid this conversion overhead?

**Question 3:** If the `Guid` is not the problem, how can I overcome this performance issue?

Comment: if you just run a select statement on this join, how long does it take?

Comment: @beauXjames select count(*) takes about 20 seconds. Oh, so you mean the conversion is not the problem...

Comment: Deleting a million rows in a single delete statement is going to take quite a bit of time because the transaction log has to record all these deletes to maintain ACIDity. Deleting that many rows you should consider doing in batches.

Comment: And no, converting a string literal to a uniqueidentifier is instant.

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean by doing them in batches? I have no idea how split them into some chunks.

Comment: As always: Please show us the query plan.

Comment: this article seems pretty good on chunking it up --> https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Comment: Some other things to consider. Do you have cascading deletes? Several indexes? multiple foreign key to check? All of these can add to the performance challenges.

Comment: how many rows has the table?

Comment: @SeanLange Yeas, there are some indexes and foreign keys which I should consider them.

Comment: @McNets Total rows are about 2,000,000

Comment: Then you can obtain better performance creating a new table and insert instead of delete.

Comment: Note that all FKs should have indexes defined... because when you delete a row, all FKs have to be checked with a look-up to see if the delete is LEGAL or if a constraint error should be thrown. If you don't have an appropriate index, this can result in table-scans of the other table, which can kill performance.

Answer (score 0):

Often I ran into similar issues when attempting to delete against a complicated query...it was as though, behind the scenes, a cursor was created and it wanted to reselect the dataset after each delete since a row was being modified.

Try deleting like the following, where you wrap the deletion effort around a really basic select statement. I took the liberty of using 'rowIndex' to identify the seed.

```
DELETE FROM CrawlRow WHERE rowIndex IN (
  SELECT rowIndex from CrawlRow cr
  INNER JOIN Crawl c ON cr.Crawl_Id = c.Id
  WHERE c.CrawlRound_Id = 'BE821DFF-3F2F-4850-80A8-10D4EF0275F5'
)
```

It's still a big task, deleting a million of anything...so don't expect too much of a performance boost.

Comment: This is going to be almost identical to the original. I don't see where the performance or improvement is here.

Comment: yeah...other than the idea of chunking, as you initially recommended---deleting from a pre-selected group against the root seed index was all i could think of.